# How to correct citations in Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, citations

Some of the publications have cited my work. But Google scholar is unable to identify those citations and link with my account. I think it is because my name in the references of article has been written differently. Is there a way I can change that?

Comment: It might be helpful to have more detail about what exactly you mean by "my name in the references of article has been written differently" - is there a mismatch between your surname as written in the official details of your paper as published versus how they spell in the citation? What's the difference - is it a typo, is it an accented character or alphabet issue, is it a name-change or dual name issue, or something else?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is known to Google and they offer the following fix via https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/citations.html#citations:

> ...
>   To fix this, you'll need to identify the specific citing articles with
>   indexing problems and work with the publisher of these articles to
>   make the necessary changes (see our inclusion guidelines for details). ...

In short, Google claims it's always reflecting the state of the internet right now. Misspellings may be part of that, but Google doesn't want to play the corrector.

Comment: please accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

You think

> Google scholar is unable to identify [some citations to my work] because my name in the references of article has been written differently

But, I doubt Google works this way, because numerous mistakes appear in references throughout the literature. Perhaps this issue will resolve itself over time as Google has more time to crawl.

Answer (score 2):

When your publications are cited, the full reference is the name of the journal/publication, date, volume and maybe even page number, on top of your own name. There is also the DOI.

So if they have misspelled your name when they cite your work, it should not matter, if they ***actually cited*** your work. Google Scholar or Pubmed or Web of Knowledge etc should be able to discern that.

What might be the case, I suspect, is that your own name is not the same between your google scholar page and the name you used in your publications.

That might be the case if you have multiple middle names (and/or initials). Or if you have changed names, due to marriage or some other reason. If you have non-standard latin letters in your name, how they are "latinified" into English might be an issue as well.

Hard to say without a concrete example

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that citations to your work are not recognized by Google Scholar because of errors in (or incompleteness of) the reference string. Such 'stray' citations can be corrected, see [Anne-Wil Harzing's guide to correcting stray citations in Google Scholar](https://harzing.com/resources/publish-or-perish/tutorial/google-scholar/stray-citations).

Note that the same problem occurs in all citation databases to some extent. Most of them have some mechanism for reporting and correcting (besides Google Scholar, at least Web of Science and Scopus do).

Comment: The link you're providing doesn't explain how to correct stray citation _on Google Scholar_. It shows how a stray citation can be correct using the Publish or Perish software.