# Google Scholar: Citations appear on co-authors' accounts but not on mine

Tags: google-scholar

**Problem:** I have several papers published all of which are picked up by Google Scholar. There's one particular paper that shows no citations, however, this is wrong. How do I know? The same paper appears to have citations when viewed from my co-authors' Google Scholar pages.

**Question:** Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

**Note:** I have other papers published with the same co-authors and the citations appear correctly on all Google Scholar accounts.

**Disclaimer:** There are several questions posted about Google Scholar not picking up citations, including [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/127459/how-to-correct-citations-in-google-scholar) on `academia.stackexchange.com`. These questions deal with missing citations in general, i.e., citations are ***not*** linked to an article. However, in my case, the citations ***are linked*** to an article, however, they do not appear on my account. In case this is important, the paper was published in 2018, so I don't think this is a case of not indexing my name yet.

Comment: Did you edit any field (e.g. date, publisher, etc.) in the Google Scholar entry of that particular paper in your profile? I have seen that doing so sometimes makes it think that it is a different paper, so it does not link the citations from the original entry to the edited version.

Comment: Contact Google Scholar - we can't edit that...

Comment: _The same paper appears to have citations when viewed from my co-authors' Google Scholar pages._ Are you sure it is _the same paper_? I.e., the exact same paper, not some version of it? If there are different versions, then add them all  and merge (a star will appear next to the citation count).

Comment: @SolarMike I have contacted Google Scholar, they haven't answer yet. When/if they do, I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: @user2768, GoodDeeds I don't remember editing any fields (paper was published in 2018) but the title was slightly different (my version included quotes as they correctly appear in the title of the paper). I made the risky decision of editing my entry to mirror that of my co-authors. I wonder if this was a good idea or not.

Comment: @Aventinus You can check this by selecting "Add articles" and searching for your paper. Does the same paper appear in the list?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yes, that fixed it! Can you please make it an answer so I can mark your solution as correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention in the comments that you edited the entry of the paper in your profile, what has probably happened is that Google Scholar now thinks that this is a separate paper, and does not link the citations from the original entry to the edited version. Unfortunately, this sometimes seems to happen when correcting certain fields in the entry created by Google Scholar.

A way to check and fix this would be to search for your paper under "Add articles", and checking if the same paper is listed there as not being in your profile. If so, you can add the original entry back to your profile and merge it with your updated entry. This should reintroduce the citation count, possibly with an asterisk next to it indicating that Google Scholar is not certain that both entries refer to the same paper.